# J3D081 personalize for Global Platform

Tags: java, smartcard, nxp-microcontroller, jcop

I purchased J3D081 smartcards from a Chinese vendor. I have only documentation for J3A081 that is incompatible.

As the card is in pre-personalization stage, I would need the APDU sequence to define the card as T1.

I am able to boot the root applet but as my documentation is for different chip, the registers are wrong.

Does someone know how to setup the card to be able to use Global Platform?

I guess simply fusing the card would render it permanently damaged as the default state is not suited for communication, right?

This is for a hobbyist project so I do not have support by NXP.

Comment: Lookin at [this page](https://www.javacardos.com/store/jcop-card.php) I would expect, that T=1 is the default for this card and only T=0 requires special handling. This can be verified by interpreting the ATR, see ISO 7816-3. Apart from that: Atttempting to work with a smartcard without the right documentation has high frustration potential, one simply gets not much helpful information from the interface.

Comment: I hear you. It is highly frustrating to have the vard in this state. I think this vendor just defaults to selling cards in T1 but the cards need some settings to be recognized by Global Platform.

Answer (score -2):

Card you mentioned if model and specs are correct on internet comes with GP 2.2 support. You should have got default test keys I guess already and that would be enough to load your applet to java card. For carrying out applet operations you can use [globalplatformpro](https://github.com/martinpaljak/GlobalPlatformPro#usage). Once the applet installation successful you would need ISO 7816-4 APDUs to communicate with your applet.

Comment: I would be happy to learn the reason of downvote and ready to make improvement upon feedback

Comment: It doesn't answer the question which is somewhat hidden in the question post: "As the card is in pre-personalization stage, I would need the APDU sequence to define the card as T1. ". As such I've just now downvoted the question and this answer, the earlier downvote was not from me then obviously.